# Blob javascript api options in making spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this generate a spreadsheet from a html table

```
$scope.exportData = function () {
        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;"
        });
        saveAs(blob, $scope.name+".xls");
    }
```

Is there any option to remove special characters or filter any row in this api?